# Function getting redeclared

Tags: c, function

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #define        MAX     10000 
 #define        CHECK   1000 
 #define        OPN     1
 #define        CLS     0
 char program[MAX];
 void si_qoute (void);
 void do_qoute (void);
 void getprogram (void);
 int main(){
     printf ("Type your code\n");
     getprogram ();
     si_quote ();
     do_quote ();
     return 0;
 }

 void si_quote (void){
     int opn[CHECK], cls[CHECK], i, lcnt = 0, opn_cnt = 0;
     for (i = 0; i < CHECK; i++)
          opn[i] = cls[i] = 0;
     for (i = 0; program[i] != '\0'; i++){
         if (program [i] == '\n')
             lcnt++;
         if (program[i] == '\''){
             opn[opn_cnt] = lcnt;
             if (program[i + 1] == '\\' &&  program[i + 3] =='\''){
                 cls[opn_cnt++] == lcnt;
                 i += 3;
             }
        else if(program[i + 2] == '\''){
            cls[opn_cnt++] == lcnt;
            i += 2;
        }
        else
            opn_cnt++;
    }
}
opn[opn_cnt] = -1;
for(i = 0; opn[i] != -1; i++)
    if (opn[i] && cls[i] == 0)
       printf ("Single Quote opened at line %d not closed \n", opn[i]);
}
void do_quote (void){
    int opn[CHECK], cls[CHECK], i, lcnt = 0, opn_cnt = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < CHECK; i++)
        opn[i] = cls[i] = 0;
    for (i = 0; program[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if (program[i] == '\n')
           lcnt++;
        if (program[i] == '\"'){
            opn[opn_cnt] = lcnt;
            while (program[++i] != '\"'){
                if (program[i] == '\\' && program [i + 1] == '\"')
                    i++;
                else if (program[i] == '\n'){
                        opn_cnt++;
                        lcnt++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (program[i] == '\"')
                cls[opn_cnt++] = lcnt;
        }
    }
    opn[opn_cnt] = cls[opn_cnt] = -1;
    for (i = 0; opn[i] != -1; i++)
        if (opn[i] && cls[i] == 0)
            printf ("Double inverted quoted opened at %d not closed \n", opn[i]);
}

void getprogram (void){
    int i, c;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF; i++)
        program[i] = c;
    program[i++] = '\n';
    program[i] = '\0';  
}
```

I am getting and error which states implicit declaration of two functions `si_quote()` and `do_quote()`. What I am intending to do is to call these functions from main. While calling a function as per my knowledge we need to try write the function name along with the argument list within parenthesis. However   as these functions doesn't accept any arguments, the parameter list is empty. I think the functions are probably getting redeclared with `int` as their return type. I can't understand what is really the issue with it. If it is getting redeclared as per my guess why is `getprogram()` still working fine. I would really appreciate if someone could help me out.

Comment: Is is a typo? You declare `si_qoute` (with **OU**) and then use `si_quote` (with **UO**).

Comment: Yes I didn't see it and panicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `si_quote` in one place and `si_qoute` in the other. These are not equal.

This simple typo makes the compiler think you declare (but not use) two of the functions and use (but do not declare) two other, completely unrelated functions.